# Is there an equivalent of `M-x check-parens` for finding unmatches braces or ['s in any buffer (not a particular mode)

Tags: buffers, commands

`M-x check-parens` finds unmatched parentheses in a buffer.
I am wondering if there is a similar command which finds unmatched `{` or `[`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `check-parens` itself for this?  The doc string (`C-h f check-parens`) tells you that it should work:

> check-parens is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `lisp.el'.
>
> (check-parens)
>
> Check for unbalanced parentheses in the current buffer.
>   More accurately, check the narrowed part of the buffer for **unbalanced
>   expressions ("sexps") in general**.  This is done according to the
>   **current syntax table** and will find **unbalanced brackets or quotes** as
>   appropriate.  (See Info node `(emacs)Parentheses'.)  If imbalance is
>   found, an error is signaled and point is left at the first unbalanced
>   character.

That tells you that it checks for unbalances sexps. If the syntax table for your current mode defines brackets and braces as sexp-balancing characters, then it should work.

Note also the cross-reference in the doc string to the relevant part of the Emacs manual. Just click that cross-reference to read that manual section for more information.

Your question title says "*in an arbitrary mode*". The behavior of `check-parens` is mode-specific. As its doc says, it checks for sexps that are unbalanced, as determined by the characters that, for that mode, balance sexps.

---

**Update:**

So now you've edited your question to make it clear that you want something that is not mode-specific. The answer to that is ***no***. There can be no mode non-specific checking for balance because *the notion of "**balanced**" is by definition mode-specific*, i.e., specific to the particular syntax.

Comment: Yes I checked it, But it doesn't work. I inserted `(){` in the scratch buffer but `M-x check-parens` is unable to find the unmatched `{`.

Comment: Then check the syntax of `{`. If you feel that it should work, then considering filing an Emacs bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Your question is weak - you don't even say what mode you are in. The behavior depends on the defined syntax of the characters (e.g. `{`). It works only if the syntax is that of a balanced delimiter. Consult the doc, if this area is unfamiliar to you. You can start with `C-h s` (command `describe-syntax`). Try `C-h s [` and `C-h s {`. See if they give you similar descriptions.

Comment: `M-x check-parens` checks unmatched parentheses everywhere, even in **scratch** buffer.

Comment: Drew, let me say to consider something like `{{}{`. This in unmatched, I think it in universally unmatched, in every mode, I think. But something like `{{}}` is universally matched.

Comment: There is no such thing as "**universally unmatched in every mode**". Likewise, "*universally matched*". And there cannot be. You can define a mode that has any syntax you like. This should be obvious - think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Check Xah's function for that. You can find it in the following link; 
[Emacs: Check Parenthesis/Brackets Balance](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_check_parens_balance.html) 
The code is as follows btw,

```
(defun xah-check-parens-balance ()
(interactive)
(let* (
     ($bracket-alist
      '( (?“ . ?”) (?‹ . ?›) (?« . ?») (?【 . ?】) (?〖 . ?〗) (?〈 . ?〉) (?《 . ?》) (?「 . ?」) (?『 . ?』) (?{ . ?}) (?\[ . ?\]) (?\( . ?\))))
     ;; regex string of all pairs to search.
     ($bregex
      (let (($tempList nil))
        (mapc
         (lambda (x)
           (push (char-to-string (car x)) $tempList)
           (push (char-to-string (cdr x)) $tempList))
         $bracket-alist)
        (regexp-opt $tempList )))
     $p1
     $p2
     ;; each entry is a vector [char position]
     ($stack '())
     ($char nil)
     $pos
     $is-closing-char-p
     $matched-open-char
     )
(if (region-active-p)
    (setq $p1 (region-beginning) $p2 (region-end))
  (setq $p1 (point-min) $p2 (point-max)))
(save-restriction
  (narrow-to-region $p1 $p2)
  (progn
    (goto-char 1)
    (while (re-search-forward $bregex nil "move")
      (setq $pos (point))
      (setq $char (char-before))
      (progn
        (setq $is-closing-char-p (rassoc $char $bracket-alist))
        (if $is-closing-char-p
            (progn
              (setq $matched-open-char
                    (if $is-closing-char-p
                        (car $is-closing-char-p)
                      (error "logic error 64823. The char %s has no matching pair."
                             (char-to-string $char))))
              (if $stack
                  (if (eq (aref (car $stack) 0) $matched-open-char )
                      (pop $stack)
                    (push (vector $char $pos) $stack ))
                (progn
                  (goto-char $pos)
                  (error "First mismtach found. the char %s has no matching pair."
                         (char-to-string $char)))))
          (push (vector $char $pos) $stack ))))
    (if $stack
        (progn
          (goto-char (aref (car $stack) 1))
          (message "Mismtach found. The char %s has no matching pair." $stack))
      (print "All brackets/quotes match."))))))
```